# how to add background image in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi can you please tell me how to add background image in angular which should display on whole application on whole page.?

**secondly** 
how to add different background image at different view on whole page ..?

here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/BTl3NwEd66IMddKtPDMR?p=preview

```
 <div bg>
<button ng-click="goTONextpage()" >Go to next Page</button> </div>
```

Comment: any update of this Question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-style` in `body` tag

```
<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url(yourImg.png)'}">
  ...
</body>
```

Setting different background for different view:

set variable named `image_path` with different values of different views

```
<body ng-style="image_path != '' && {'background-image':'url('+image_path+')'}" >
  ...
<body>
```

Comment: can you make plunker ..!! it will add in all  view ? can i add class which is define in css

Comment: check this plunker ..http://plnkr.co/edit/KfY9Xo2br3AD6UOzoZlE?p=preview..It doesn't work for me

Comment: can you please give plunker ?